# How to include css and javascript to main template head section using the grails web framework

Tags: grails, sitemesh

I have been using the grails UI performance plugin which handles this with the p:dependantJavascript taglibs.

So say im working on a template `_someTemplate.gsp` and this template only has the following content:

```
<div onclick="doSomething()">someContent</div>
```

now i would like to add the javascript `doSomething()` to the head section of the page whenever this template is loaded. Is ther any grails magic to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put [javascript tag](http://www.grails.org/Tag+-+javascript) in the template, like:

```
<g:javascript src="file.js"/>
```

**UPDATE**: The general way to include any javascript & CSS file into the head of a layout is to create a full template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><g:layoutTitle default="An example decorator" /></title>
        <!-- javascript & css go here, just like normal gsp/html page -->
        <g:layoutHead /> <!-- for the specific page -->
    </head>
    <body>

        <g:layoutBody /> <!-- render the specific page body -->

        <div onclick="doSomething()">someContent</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

More detailed instructions can be found [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.4%20Layouts%20with%20Sitemesh).

Comment: what about ('inline') javascript that is just a code block? not external resource?

Comment: @netbrain: I don't know if Grails support the case, but it's surely not a good practice to include the same function in all the pages. It would be more nicer if you write that inline javascript in a file, then include it: users only need to download that file once.

Comment: I guess your right, but if you have a lot of small javascript functions over many pages then this could result in many javascript files. ofc. you can always combine them two one large js file, but then you have to download a large file when your only using 1% of it.

Comment: and btw, what about css files?

Comment: @netbrain: the only way I could think of to satisfy your request is creating a layout instead of a template(details in updated answer). But I think putting javascript functions in a large files seems to be easier to maintain.

Comment: The JS file should only get loaded once, anyway.

Comment: from a development perspective its harder to work with a single large js file and a single large css file. However, i think i found a solution to keep production structure and development structure separated. Google has a apache module caled pagespeed, with this module apache will automatically merge all js files and css files to one file and minify it.